# Cannot import name 'evaluate' from 'bleu'

Tags: python, bleu

I'm trying to to do this 
 
`from bleu import evaluate`
 
 But I get the following error: 
 
ImportError: cannot import name 'evaluate' from 'bleu' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bleu/**init**.py) 
 
 Version I'm using pip install bleu==0.1.0 
 I'm trying to run a code which has this so please help

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the evaluate() method was deprecated in version 1.0.5 (functionally replaced by model_selection.cross_validate()) and was removed in version 1.1.0.

Comment: Still getting the error ImportError: cannot import name 'cross_validate' from 'bleu'

Comment: Try this: from surprise.model_selection import cross_validate

Comment: Can you share some insight on what you are working on? It's hard to make recommendations without knowing what the use is.

Comment: It is imported in this file https://github.com/iamsiddhantsahu/ImageCapTransformer/blob/master/solver.py

Comment: I'm sorry mate, hopefully someone else can provide a solution for you. All I can tell is is that the original evaluate() was deprecated and removed. Good luck!